# How can I generate a download link which downloads a google drive folder as a zip?

Tags: google-drive

I know [it is possible](https://www.wonderplugin.com/online-tools/google-drive-direct-link-generator/) to generate a permanent download link for files on Google Drive.

My question here is is there a way to generate a URL which will serve as a permanent download link for a Google Drive folder? i.e. it downloads the folder as a zip.

I already know you can do this using the web-interface (just right-click on the folder and download), but I am looking for a way to generate a link that will download the file directly.